# MySQL, Merge selects in order of one record from each select

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a table that contains too many records and each bunch of records belong to someone:

```
---------------------
id | data | username
---------------------
1  | 10   | ali
2  | 11   | ali
3  | 12   | ali
4  | 20   | omid
5  | 21   | omid
6  | 30   | reza
```

now I want to create a query to result me like this:

```
1-10-ali
4-20-omid
6-30-reza
2-11-ali
5-21-omid
3-12-ali
```

Is there anyway to create a query to result me one record per each username and then one from another, and another to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have a ranking system so you can use UDV (user defined variables) to rank your records like so.

```
SELECT id, `data`, name
FROM
( SELECT 
    id, `data`, name,
    @rank := if(@name = name, @rank + 1, 1) as rank,
    @name := name
  FROM test
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 1, @name := '') temp
  ORDER BY name, `data`
) t
ORDER BY t.rank, t.name, t.data
```

**[Sql Fiddle to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/374d7/1)**

Output:

```
+---------------------+
| id  | data |  name  |
+-----+------+--------+
|  1  |  10  |  ali   |
+---------------------+
|  4  |  20  |  omid  |
+---------------------+ 
|  6  |  30  |  reza  |
+---------------------+ 
|  2  |  11  |  ali   |
+---------------------+
|  5  |  21  |  omid  |
+---------------------+ 
|  3  |  12  |  ali   |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: THANKS ! it working on fiddle, i will test it on mysql and let you now the result

Answer (score 0):

The classic SQL approach is a self join and grouping that lets you determine a row's ranking position by counting the number of rows that come before it. As this is probably slower I doubt I could talk you out of the proprietary method but I mention it to give you an alternative.

```
select t.id, min(t.`data`), min(t.username)
from test t inner join test t2
    on t2.username = t.username and t2.id <= t.id
group by t.id
order by count(*), min(t.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example would work with

```
SELECT id, `data`, name
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY  `data` % 10,
              username
              `data`;
```

If `data` and `username` do not have the desired pattern, then improve on the example.